# jquery not updating div.text() with json data unless added to string?

Tags: jquery, json

If I call

`$('#display').text('' + data.Display);`

then my div is populated with the correct value

if I call

`$('#display').text(data.Display);`

then it is not populated?

`data` is coming from a getJson call and is of the format `Display: "AB01 AAAA 0000 0000 1111 2222 2233 3"`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getButton').click(function () {

    var id = $('#valueId').val();
    $('#Display').text('');

    $.getJSON('api/Generate/', { 'IdNumber': id })
      .done(function (data) {
          $('#Display').text('' + data.Display); // fails here unless added to ''
      })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
          $('#error').text('Error: ' + err);
      });
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to put the data.Display into the correct tag, without having to add it to an empty string?

Comment: What type is `data.Display` (since it doesn't seem like it's a string)?

Comment: According to VS (this is inside MVC application) it's a string already?

Comment: This was down to a a JQueryUI version issue!  Updated JQueryUI and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As just a blind shot in the dark, maybe try

```
$('#Display').text(data.Display.toString());
```

When you called the original function as

```
$('#display').text('' + data.Display);
```

you are coercing your `data.Display` to a string, so it displays correctly. Automatic coercion stops happening when you remove the string concatenation, however.

Comment: Hmm...VS is telling me this is already a string? Guess it's lying!

Answer (score 0):

```
data.Display.toString()  ?
```

Correct mе if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was down to a JQueryUI version issue.  The particular version (1.8.20) was for some reason seeing `{field: "string"}` as an object.

Updated to 1.10.3 and now `{field: "string"}` is a string!